# Javascript and Xml not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, xml

```
if(status == "meeting")
{ 
   console.log("StartTime: " + form.mytime.value); //display 17:00
   xmlReplace("CFStatus", "InMeeting"); // change the CFstatus == in Meeting
   time = form.mytime.value + ":00"; //display 17:00:00 for format purpose
   xmlReplace("StartTime", time); // create new variable Startime time  
}
```

then , I properly pass all the information to the if statement below, But for some reason the time is displaying 00:00:00

```
if($CFStatus.text() == "InMeeting")
{   
$time = $xml.find("StartTime");
console.log("StartTimebefore:" + $time.text());  //00:00:00   How come it display 00:00:00????
    localStorage.setItem("StartTime", $time.text());
document.getElementById("mytime").setAttribute("value", $time.text());
$('#mytime').trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value':$time.text()});
console.log("StartTimeafter:" + $time.text()); //00:00:00
}
```

Did i pass any information wrong?

Comment: You've provided very little information for any one to go on. What is the code supposed to do, what is trying to access. It kind of sounds as if you haven't provided a permission in the manifest file of your app.

Comment: Where is java here? Or anything android related for that matter? All I see is php script without much info.

Comment: That isn't php... I'm pretty sure it's javascript

Comment: Guys i just add a new question.. i erased the other one, sorry if i cant provide lot of information for personal reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug with android

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11973

It is caused by passing null to JSON.parse.  You need to explicitly check that the argument isn't null as on android, this throws an exception.